# Objects having knowledge of each other

Tags: php, zend-framework

In Zend Framework ,Zend_Application object has a bootstrap object to bootstrap or configure
the components.Bootstrap class in turn have access to zend_application object to access configuration parameters.
My Question is that what kind of pattern is this or is it a code smell because of circular dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Zend Framework 1 is bloated, that's for sure.**

The reason for that `$_application` property representing a bi-directional relation is due to the module's independent bootstrap files.

It's strange, I think, because when dealing with modules, instead of having the `Zend_Aplication` set you'll have the main bootstrap instead:

```
/**
 * Set application/parent bootstrap
 *
 * @param  Zend_Application|Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrapper $application
 * @return Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract
 */
public function setApplication($application)
{
    if (($application instanceof Zend_Application)
        || ($application instanceof Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrapper)
    ) {
        if ($application === $this) {
            throw new Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception('Cannot set application to same object; creates recursion');
        }
        $this->_application = $application;
    } else {
        throw new Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception('Invalid application provided to bootstrap constructor (received "' . get_class($application) . '" instance)');
    }
    return $this;
}
```

There's a lot of code smell too:

```
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * Sets application object, initializes options, and prepares list of
 * initializer methods.
 *
 * @param  Zend_Application|Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrapper $application
 * @return void
 * @throws Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception When invalid application is provided
 */
public function __construct($application)
{
    $this->setApplication($application);
    $options = $application->getOptions();
    $this->setOptions($options);
}
```

The boostrap file need the options, so instead of [asking for the options](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0), it expects the Zend_Application to then get the options:

```
$options = $application->getOptions();
$this->setOptions($options);
```

It seems like they simply ignore the type of interface expected by the setApplication() method and it can be one of the followings:

- Zend_Application
- Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrapper
- Zend_Application_Bootstrap_ResourceBootstrapper

**I would give up trying to understand this mess and switch to ZF 2, though ;)**

Comment: I wouldn't be in such rush, especially knowing how ZF2 perform compared to ZF1 (bloated or not).

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com The idea is that it's better to study the ZF2 source code than the ZF1. Since the OP did not mentioned any errors, only wondered if there's code smell. The answer is: **Yes**